# How to create undirected (i)graph in R for protein-interaction data with tissue information?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, igraph, undirected-graph, protein-database

I am new to bioinformatics in general and would really appreciate some help and tips with the project Im working on.

My data of protein-protein interactions is stored in a table (in MySQL) with binary information about tissue-specificity. Now I am trying to create an undirected graph with igraph in R, but could not understand what type of data structure I should use without losing the tissue-information (Adjacency matrix, edge list..?).

Thank you in advance!

The data itself about 200k rows, but here is an example of the structure:

| symbol1 | symbol2 | adipose_tissue | adrenal_gland | amygdala | bone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| POT1 | PRMT7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| CNBP | HNRNPAB | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| TRIAP1 | BAG3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| NR5A1 | RALY | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| TPI1 | CCDC8 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| MRPS22 | BARD1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| TOP2A | CCDC8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| MYH9 | TRIM72 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ATXN7 | TAF12 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| PSEN1 | STT3B | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| ATP5F1 | TSG101 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| BRCA1 | UTP4 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: *whispers* have you tried biostars yet?

Comment: Hi, as is already stated in an answer below, igraph can do what you're interested in, but it would be helpful to include an accessible small example of the data you're working with. Something like 5-10 rows of data, is usually sufficient for creation of examples that can help you. Screenshots aren't usually easily portable to code in this format.

Comment: @nick Thank you for the feedback! Hope it's better now..

Comment: This is a little late to the game, but including your data as a string of code that can be copy-pasted is the preferred method of including an example, followed by linking to publicly available data. The answer below that generates the data in a small code block is be a good example.

Answer (score 1):

Bioinformatics apart, this is a question of data-wrangling in igraph. Igraph is capable of building graph-objects from both matrices and lists in many formats, so one should avoid too much pre-conversion. I suggest you build your graph using `graph_from_data_frame()`

I assume that the data structure described above is relational and therefore basically already an edge-list of relations between proteins `uniprot2` and `uniprot2`. This mockup sample-data would then mimics your data-structure.

```
data <- data.frame(uniprot1 = c('Q94X','Q95X','Q435','QUUU','0982'),
                   uniprot2 = c('QUUU','Q94X','Q95X','Q95X','Q94X'),
                   symbol = c('Symbol A', 'Symbol B', 'Symbol C','Symbol D',' Symbol E'),
                   adipose_tissue = c(1,0,0,1,1),
                   bone=c(0,0,0,1,1))
```

To keep variables other than just the relational edges between vertices, you can either create them alongside your graph-objects, or add and manipulate them later manually.

Attributes naturally belong either to vertices or to edges. A veracity-attribute in your data would be a protein name, size or other characteristic. An edge-attribute would be the relational strength, type, or any other characteristic of the link between two proteins. If your graph would have a veracity called `understandable_name_of_protein` you'd access it like so:

`V(g)$understandable_name_of_protein`

Edge-attributes follow the same principle through `E(g)$attribute`. When you load the example data above, all your edge-attributes should jump right into your graph like this:

```
# Build an undirected graph using the edges described in `data`
g <- graph_from_data_frame(data, directed=FALSE)
# Check sure that data was correctly imported as edge-attributes
E(g)$bone
# Add the edge-attribut `color` which will be displayed when plotting the graph
E(g)$color <- ifelse(E(g)$bone == 0, 'green','black')
# plot to see the graph with the bone-attribute visible as edge-color
plot(g)
```